# TOMCAT 6 SSL Error: Alias name does not identify a key entry

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I'm trying to configure the keystore after I have received the CA.
I received one intermediate CA and the CA. I have imported them using this commands

```
keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore B1i.keystore

keytool -import -alias root -keystore ".\B1iXcellerator\B1i.keystore" -trustcacerts -file ".\B1iXcellerator\int.crt"

keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore ".\B1iXcellerator\B1i.keystore" -trustcacerts -file ".\B1iXcellerator\ssmobile2.crt"
```

Your access key file contains 2 entries

**root**, 14-sept.-2017, trustedCertEntry,
Empreinte du certificat (SHA1) : 55:83:E3:E1:A7:51:17:21:1E:AF:C8:5E:D1:15:BB:C1
:AC:96:9D:B5

**tomcat**, 14-sept.-2017, trustedCertEntry,
Empreinte du certificat (SHA1) : DF:1C:D4:79:02:D5:59:D2:94:1D:DE:D5:73:99:2D:1A
:25:09:BC:49

And in the server.xml I changed this:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="./webapps/B1iXcellerator/B1i.keystore" keyAlias="tomcat" keystorePass="******"/>
```

But I'm getting the error 
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.io.IOException: Alias name tomcat does not identify a key entry

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
keytool -delete -alias tomcat -keystore B1i.keystore
```

You probably deleted your private key with this step. You should have omitted this step, and used the `tomcat` alas in the next steps: see below.

```
keytool -import -alias root -keystore ".\B1iXcellerator\B1i.keystore" -trustcacerts -file ".\B1iXcellerator\int.crt"
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore ".\B1iXcellerator\B1i.keystore" -trustcacerts -file ".\B1iXcellerator\ssmobile2.crt"
```

These steps don't have the desired effect unless there was already a private key entry with alias 'root'.

You are probably going to have to start again, generating a new keypair, a new CSR, getting it re-signed. This time, import the signed certificates *without* the `-trustcacerts` option, using the same alias as the keypair, and import the root certificates *with* `-trustcacerts` and a different alias (thanks @dave_thompson_085).

And don't delete things when you don't know what they are.

Comment: int.crt is presumably an intermediate being imported as trustedcert so _its_ alias 'root' should not exist; it is the alias used for the (new) leaf cert here 'tomcat' that must exist and be/contain the privatekey.

Comment: So I request a new certificate and I simply do the keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore ".\B1iXcellerator\B1i.keystore" -trustcacerts -file ".\B1iXcellerator\int.crt"
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore ".\B1iXcellerator\B1i.keystore" -trustcacerts -file ".\B1iXcellerator\ssmobile2.crt"? How does it work, how do they know which one is the intermediate and the CA?

Comment: I did as you said but I get the following error: keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match when trying to import the intermediate certificate

Comment: OK, I started over again. Now I have a PrivateKEyEntry with alias tomcat. I couldn't import the intermediate and the CA with alias tomcat, so I imported with other alias. The import was successful. Now I have 3 entries in the keystore. But it still doesn't work (certification error in the browser)

Here's the error in the log document Protocol handler start failed: java.io.IOException: Alias name tomcat does not identify a key entry

Comment: So you still don't have a `PrivateKeyEntry` with alias 'tomcat'. That's the meaning of the error message. There's not enough information in your comments to go any further.